# Nativescript-vue version 3 support?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is there already support for vue 3 or do we have to wait for another version?
looking in the documentation I can not find information about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`nativescript-vue` GitHub Issue #583](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/583):

- Support for Vue 3 is not yet officially released
- There is a [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/rigor789/nativescript-vue-next) and [NPM package (`nativescript-vue@3.0.0-dev.4`)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-vue/v/3.0.0-dev.4), but no documentation.
- [Video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuEEF-QvfmU)

Answer (score 1):

They released a beta now for NativeScript Vue 3.
https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue